# update daily ==> Clickonce or UAB(update application Block)

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

Hi for updating an application daily which one is better for a WPF application?
clickonce or UAB?
or more options?
thanks of your attentions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce was intended for smart client applications, and is good for a WPF application, depending on what else is going on in it. If you need it to be installed for all users, or need to be writing to the registry during installation, it won't work.

We use it at my company, and used to put out a lot of updates. We have thousands of customers, and have had great success with ClickOnce.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about it in [this post on my blog](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2007/08/07/How-To-Write-an-Automatic-Update-System-Part-8.aspx) a while ago.

In short:

- ClickOnce is very nice but fairly limited, use it if you can.
- UAB is too big and heavy weight for an updater, I don't have personal experience with it.
- There are a lot of [commercial and open source options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net) that look better than UAB