# A check for update feature

Tags: .net

I am creating a small .NET 4 application that will require small but frequent updates.  Are there free/cheap services out there that will provide an update feature?  Or, is this something that has to be developed into the application?

Comment: Does click once update?  Looking into it, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-update library for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)

Comment: Cheers, however, this looks a bit dated?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mitch's comment:

click-once

http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2007/08/07/How-To-Write-an-Automatic-Update-System-Part-8.aspx

> ClickOnce
>
> ClickOnce is built into .net (version
>   2.0 and later) and is extremely easy to use, all you have to install your
>   software using ClickOnce. You prepare
>   the ClickOnce package – just a few
>   files on a web server (all your
>   program files and a manifest file that
>   can be automatically generated by
>   developer studio).
>
> The user clicks a link to the manifest
>   file and .net will magically download
>   and install your program and all
>   prerequisites (the .net framework
>   itself, SQL server express etc.).
>
> If your customer already have all
>   prerequisites on his/hers computer
>   ClickOnce installation is quick and
>   painless, if some of the prerequisites
>   (especially the .net framework) are
>   missing the installation is long and
>   not so painless.
>
> An important feature of ClickOnce (at
>   least from this post point of view) is
>   that it includes an auto-update
>   feature, you replace the files on the
>   server with the latest version and
>   clients will update automatically.
>
> Highly recommended if you can expect
>   your prerequisites are already
>   installed on your customer's computer.