# Automatically Update WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to have my WPF application pull updates across the internet.

I'm not planning to use ClickOnce because it doesn't support any security mechanism other than Windows Integrated, and that too, only over an intranet.

Is there anything (free open source software) out there to help me with this?

Practical advice would be appreciated, too.

Comment: I think it would be useful to find out why you don't want to use ClickOnce, as that may restrict or allow other options

Comment: ClickOnce doesn't support any security mechanism other than Windows Integrated, and that too, only over an intranet.

Comment: as our application grows i find myself in need of walking away from click once for two reason: 1. it is installed by a user, forcing admins to login as users and installing it manually. 2. for different clients we have different config files which forces me to create a separate click-once deployment. would be easier just being able to copy the right config file.

Comment: You can try Autoupdater.NET from [codeplex](http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/) I developed it my self and it works very well in my applications. Not tested with WPF but it should work.
You just have to add one line in your code and its done.

Comment: Related question: [Auto-update library for .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/691663/148412)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[NetSparkle](https://github.com/NetSparkleUpdater/NetSparkle) seems a fairly robust auto update package and is compatible with WPF

This framework contains a lot of features, please check them out:

- True self-updating, no work required
  from user based on Windows Installer
  packages
- Uses appcasts for release information
- Displays release news to the user via
  Internet Explorer Control
- Displays a detailed progress window
  to the user
- NetSparkle requires no code in your
  app, so it's trivial to upgrade or
  remove the module
- Seamless integration—there's no
  mention of NetSparkle; your icons and
  app name are used
- Supports DSA signatures for
  ultra-secure updates
  UpdateChecker-Helper for start menu
  integration

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like this is now something called AutoUpdater.NET. http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/ The language on the project page sounds very similar and the UI looks very similar as well. NetSparkle was last updated in 2011, while AutoUpdater.NET was last updated in 2013. Maybe a new name for the same project? It's also available through NuGet.

Comment: [AUTO UPDATER -GITHUB](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET)

Answer (score 9):

[Shimmer](https://github.com/github/Shimmer) might be what you're looking for -"it's like ClickOnce but Works"

**Edit**: The thing is now called [Squirrel.Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows)

Comment: Sounds promising. Actively developed.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/246) keep Squirrel from working and the project seems abandoned.

Comment: Link to the issue is not valid anymore. Please update your comment, @Shywim

Comment: @Shywim the link works for me; it opens an issue in github titled `Run installer of a dependency #246`.

Comment: Wow - what a killer solution! I didn't have admin rights to install VIA the MS App Store, however i was able to install the NuGet Package Explorer though the NuGet link without any issues. Easy to understand concept(s), and sooooo many resources and features are provided at no cost.

Answer (score 4):

ClickOnce is by far the simplest solution.

Otherwise, there are some CodeProject articles which describe options.  For example:

- [Application Auto Update in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/autoupdate.aspx) - Shows how to self-update.  Could easily be translated to C#.
- [Adding automatic updates to your program](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/DDayUpdate_Part1.aspx) - Works via a bootstrapping application.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old questions, and some new alternatives has come along!

I found Squirrel to be awsome! Check it out here:

https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

Comment: What do you think of [WinSparkle](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle)?

Comment: Without knowing too much about the project it looks like fairly active in the repo, but no example of apps using in. I think Squirrel has a better installer UI, and I know after using Squirrel now for over a year in production that it's working awsome.