# WPF program auto software update

Tags: wpf, auto-update

I developed a WPF Setup application. This app can not update itself automaticly. For update, users should remove the app and re-install it.

My app is taking data from SQL Server 2008 which is on my server. In other words, app works like a browser. All data came from my server.

How can I inform my users and update app automaticly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [click once (auto update)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx).

If you dont want to use clickonce, you can use [netsparkle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5040651/649524)

[Deploy and update smart client  projects using central server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163973.aspx) -> uses click once

[Adding automatic updates to your app](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19623/Adding-automatic-updates-to-your-program-Part-1) -> It does not use click once itself, though consume clickonce manifests.

[Set up net sparkle autoupdate](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: I have read both pages but I don't understand how Click Once or Netsparkle removes and re-installs application or overide installed app.

It seems like these two solutions just inform users about update?

Comment: no, they can use used to implement auto update, though it requires some custom [logic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19623/Adding-automatic-updates-to-your-program-Part-1).  [Net sparkle autoupdate](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: I'll try solutions in links you gave in your last comment. And, I am going to share the result. I hope I can make it.