# Best way to auto update C# desktop intranet apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, version-control, desktop-application

New to programming. Just finished my first app but am struggling making sure all end users are using the latest compiled version of my desktop app. Is there a bonified approach to this that I would be able to implement given my limited expertise? (I only know how to c# in desktop app environment so far).

Thanks tremendously in advance!

PS I am deploying with setup project in VS ans storing MSI installer on a shared network drive at my business

Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006584/automatically-update-wpf-application

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net

Comment: another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623418/what-alternatives-are-there-to-clickonce

Comment: Personally, I would use Squirrel.Windows. It's still active and is also used by most "electron" apps like VS Code. Imagine your application's auto-update feature as seamless as with VS Code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-update library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)