# What is the state-of-the-art auto-update technique?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have come across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net) but it is more than 2 years old. I am building a small library with a DLL file and a bunch of resource files. I want to the client to have an updated version of these files whenever they change on my server. How would I go about achieving this?

There were two options:

- [AppUpdater](http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/)
- [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

But I am interested in knowing if there have been any recent developments in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought I haven't tried it yet, [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) might also be worth a try.
And you might find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net) useful.

Answer (score 1):

If client is another developer consuming your dlls NuGet is very good

http://nuget.codeplex.com/