# Outlook VSTO addin deployment .NET, auto update tool from web aside from ClickOnce?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, clickonce, add-in

Hi guys I need to know if there is a tool that I can use to have my outlook addin(assume that it has been successfully installed to many users) get auto updates from a web server? I'm thinking of ClickOnce but I'm not sure of using it since there are drawbacks on its implementation.

Do you have any suggestions? or should I deploy it with ClickOnce?

any of you have an opinion/experience with ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: Hi there, if my answer helped you & it was correct, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

This is an article that describe how to add an automatic update service for an application, give it a look: [Adding automatic updates to your program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19623/Adding-automatic-updates-to-your-program-Part-1)

**Updated:**

Another interesting approach is the "[.NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)" which is the answer of a similar question "[Auto-update library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)" where you can find other interesting answers too.